# Xamarin Android app not calling SOAP web service with BlackBerry UEM

Tags: android, xamarin, soap, blackberry

We have a Xamarin Forms Android app that makes SOAP-based web service calls to one of our servers.  The app works fine in all scenarios except for one customer who use a BlackBerry UEM, where the first web service method call times out.

The same web service call simulated using ApiClient (Postman for Android) works without timing out.

The web service bindings were created in Visual Studio 2019 as a Web Reference.

We're aware of a BlackBerry Dynamics SDK for Xamarin but, if it is necessary to use this, we have no idea what we'd need to do with it to make web service calls work.

Has anybody come across this issue or have any ideas?

Comment: What mode is the customer using on their devices?  Are they using Android Enterprise with BSCP (BlackBerry Secure Connect Plus, which is a VPN like connection)?  Or is this a non managed device and they are using BlackBerry Dynamics apps?  Or some combination of both?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the BlackBerry products but the customer used the term "BlackBerry VPN" so I guess they're using BSCP.  Also, the app has some managed options which I'm guessing implies the same.

Comment: Finding these details will be key to resolving this issue.  If they are using Android Enterprise, BSCP is an option and could allow your application to use it to connect to resources behind the customer's firewall.  If they are not using Android Enterprise (or using AE without BSCP) then the BlackBerry Dynamics SDK could be used to provide secure connectivity behind the customer's firewall. Knowing their configuration is important to determine the method that could be used to reach their intranet. This assumes the destination server is not publicly available on the Internet.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping.  I am waiting to hear from the customer about their configuration.  You are correct, the server is not publicly available.

Comment: The customer is using BlackBerry UEM 12.13.1.  They are not using BlackBerry Dynamics. They do use Samsung KNOX but are planning to move to the Android for Enterprise container with devices on Android 10.  All connectivity back to internal service is via a VPN policy that pushes all comms for the apps down the BlackBerry Secure Connect Plus VPN tunnel.

Comment: BlackBerry Secure Connect Plus should be invisible to your app, no changes should be required.  And you say Android Postman on the same device is able to make the call?  If so I recommend taking a look at the BlackBerry Proxy logs for both connections for clues on what is going on.  The customer could open a case with BlackBerry Support to help with the log review.

Comment: We have more information from another customer with the same or similar issue: the app is able to use the web service when there is no PAC file configured, but an exception occurs when there is a PAC file hosted on their internal web server (even though the file directly routes the traffic).

Comment: The PAC file must also be configured within your customer's BlackBerry UEM for it to be utilized by applications using BlackBerry Secure Connect Plus (BSCP). I recommend having your customer contact BlackBerry UEM Support to verify it has been set up correctly. They'll need to take a look at the customer's BSCP logs to determine what is happening.

Comment: We have replaced the SOAP proxy class generated by Visual Studio with our own and most of the problems seem to have been resolved.  A Wireshark network trace revealed a few differences in the HTTP headers between the two methods of calling SOAP methods but it seems strange that that would cause such a major failure (and only on a BlackBerry network).  Without access to the customer's network, we are unable to narrow down the exact difference that causes problems.